# ¿Alguien sabe cómo trabajar con datos de ficheros?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Quiero trabajar con los datos de este fichero, pero no sé cómo, tan sólo sé abrir el archivo y leerlo, pero no sé cómo identificar línea por línea, diferenciar frases, etc.

Los datos satisfacen los siguientes términos:

- *cause_of_death*: Causa de muerte registrada.
- *Date*: fecha en formato YYYMMDD, por ejemplo: 20180523
- *Dead*: cantidad de muertes confirmadas asociadas al evento.
- *Missing*: cantidad de desaparecidos asociados al evento.
- *Latitude*: latitud asociada al evento.
- *Longitude*: longitud asociada al evento.

migraciones.txt

> drowned 20150430 41 12 540 131.42
>
> drowned 20150430 13 3 510 173.56
>
> car_accident 20150430 1 63 501 132.57
>
> shot_by_police 20150430 53 3 630 163.51

Answer (score 2):

> No sé cómo identificar línea por línea, diferenciar frases, etc.

Por lo que veo, tu archivo es de texto, así que podrás usar el [operador de extracción de datos (`>>`) de los flujos (*stream*) de datos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

```
struct muertes
{
    std::string motivo;
    unsigned int fecha;
    unsigned int muertos;
    unsigned int desaparecidos;
    float latitud;
    float longitud;
};

if (std::ifstream migraciones{"migraciones.txt"})
{
    muertes m;
    migraciones >> m.motivo;
    migraciones >> m.fecha;
    migraciones >> m.muertos;
    migraciones >> m.desaparecidos;
    migraciones >> m.latitud;
    migraciones >> m.longitud;
}
```

Si haces que la lectura esté en un bucle, puedes leer línea por línea:

```
if (std::ifstream migraciones{"migraciones.txt"})
{
    muertes m;
    while (migraciones >> m.motivo &&
        migraciones >> m.fecha &&
        migraciones >> m.muertos &&
        migraciones >> m.desaparecidos &&
        migraciones >> m.latitud &&
        migraciones >> m.longitud)
    {
        // Tratar los datos.
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AcnSCctm9TwFaPTi)</kbd>.